# Azure AD SSO - Basic Authentication

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, basic-authentication

Are on-premise web applications using Basic Authentication method supported by Azure AD Single Sign-On ?

Comment: Could you explain what you refer by "Basic" - The exact type of Auth supported by the on premise Web application?